# Why "Enter passphrase for key 'devenv-key.pem' " if I didn't create any passprhase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I'm launching a EC2 from AWS on CLI. After I launch I can't ssh to it. When I try, I get the following message where I'm stuck:

`Enter passphrase for key 'devenv-key.pem':`

following the tutorial: [aws tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html)

Using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this tutorial you use CLI to create your .pem file. At the present moment the CLI is not creating .pem files that work with openSSH (at least on your OS). So create your .pem file on aws website and everything will work!

Comment: You know you're talking to yourself right?

Comment: I think it is friendly to read for someane with the same problem

Comment: I will add the tutorial I'm following. Well I don't have enough knowledge to claim that it's a problem on any OS with openSSH. On ubuntu 16.04 it is not working.

Comment: you're right. Edited

Comment: Looks much better, thanks!  I'll delete my suggestions since they're pointless now. ; )

Comment: Feedback is wellcome. I edited both question and answer